# Replace log4j Conversion pattern with sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to replace whenever the actual text contains need to be replaced with text output in sed. It doesn't work to me.

Actual Text :

```
%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
```

Text output which i need

```
%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] - %X{Sample} - %m%n
```

Command :

```
sed -i "/<param name=\"ConversionPattern\" value=\"%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n\"\/>/s@@<param name=\"ConversionPattern\" value=\"%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] - %X{Sample} - %m%n\"\/>@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
sed -E 's/(.*\])[[:space:]]++(.*)$/\1 [%t] - %X{Sample} - \2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s substitution capability and substituting everything from starting to till `]` and keeping it in 1st back reference, then keep everything after it into 2nd back reference. While substituting it mentioning `- %X{Sample} -` between 2 of the back references values to insert new text.

***NOTE:*** Above code will print the output on terminal, once you are happy with above results, then you could run above command with `sed -i` option to perform an in-place save.

Comment: My exact line looks like this <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/> and it has to be replaced with <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] - %X{Sample} - %m%n">

Comment: @user1485267, sure, could you please try my updated code once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @user1485267, with your shown samples it worked fine. Sorry to day but answers will be given as per shown samples. Is your actual file is different from shown samples? Kindly do let me know then.

Comment: Yes it works fine. But when i do with sed -i it throws an error like invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @user1485267, please run it like `sed -i -E 's/(.*\])[[:space:]]++(.*)$/\1 [%t] - %X{Sample} - \2/' file` and it should fly then, I have successfully tested it, let me know if All is Well with this one.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly, Thanks Ravi. But if the final output string already present in the file it should not replace. But with your command it doesn't search the string if it is already present then it will be a problem to me.

Comment: @user1485267, ok, please try `sed -E '/\(%X\{Sample\}\)/! s/(.*\])[[:space:]]++(.*)$/\1 [%t] - %X{Sample} - \2/' file` once if you are happy with results then use `-i` option as used above, this will substitute only those lines where string is not found.

Comment: No it didnt work, it is replacing on top of that.

Comment: @user1485267, `sed  -E '/(%X\{Sample\})/! s/(.*\])[[:space:]]++(.*)$/\1 [%t] - %X{Sample} - \2/' file` has worked for me fine, eg--> `<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>` changed to `<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] - %X{Sample} - %m%n"/>` AND line `<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] - %X{Sample} - %m%n"/>` is not at all changed when I tested.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/][[:blank:]]+(%m%n)/] - %X{Sample} - \1/' log4j.config

cat log4j.config

%d{ConversionPattern} %-5p [%c{1}] - %X{Sample} - %m%n
```